# iOS TableView Row Deletion

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When using the function `editActionsForRowAt` to delete the cells of a table, it requires the user to take action to delete (swiping and tapping or swiping fully across the cell) is there a way to call this without the user having to do anything?

Comment: U can customise ur code. U can achieve that behaviour. We can't cal delegate method from any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can call this method yourself from the code, but as mentioned in other answers you shouldn't call methods that are called by delegate owners.

Better way of doing this would be to [extract](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) contents of `tableView(_:editActionsForRowAt)` and call new extracted method from it **and** from anywhere you want too.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let removeAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete", handler: { [weak self] action, indexPath in
        // Call extracted method
        self?.extractedAction(at: indexPath)
    })
    return [removeAction]
}

func extractedAction(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Your old delete from old tableView(_:editActionsForRowAt) logic goes here.
}

func anyOtherPlaceInYourCode() {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(...) // which row?
    extractedAction(at: indexPath) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of safety and style, you should never call a method that's a delegate method or other event owned by Cocoa.

But nothing stops you from "factoring out" that functionality, into a method that `editActionsForRowAt` calls and that you can call as well.